# How could i express this situation properly

Tags: american-english

At past, I thought :
If i go to the cafe at 7 pm, i can meet my friend at there.

But i couldn't meet him.

I want to express the situation at present. 
I tried :
**"I thought that if i go to the cafe at 7 pm, i can meet my friend at there. But i couldn't meet him."**

Is this right? Using both if and thought is very confusing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first-person singular objective pronoun is "I" -- capitalized.  And you are muddling up present and past tense.  Plus you would never say "at there".

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks. So how could i say the situation?

Comment: Present tense might be:  I think that because it's 7pm and I'm at the cafe, I should be able to find my friend here, but I don't see him.

Comment: The only way that you could mix the tenses is by using directtly reported speech for the thought and past tense for the result as in _I thought "If I go to the cafe at 7:00 pm I can meet my friend there.", but I couldn't meet him._ The present tense then only appears in the direct quotation which is placed in the past by 'I thought'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were went to the café but didn't see him there than you could say, "I went to the café at 7 pm to see my friend, but couldn't find him."

If something got in the way of you going than you could say, "I was going to meet my friend at the café at 7 pm, but something got in the way. (say what got in the way)"

If you were going to meet him, but couldn't bring yourself to do it, than you could say, "I was going to meet my friend at the café at 7 pm, but I couldn't bring myself to go."